# How to run a long stored procedure asynchronously and check on its progress

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, asynchronous, ado.net

I have a WPF application that calls a SQL Server stored procedure that takes a few minutes to run. This stored procedure writes to a log table during its processing. I'd like to show the log messages in a grid while the stored procedure is running.

I have a while loop that seems to be working while it checks the `IAsyncResult` for `IsCompleted`, but my grid does not display anything until the main stored procedure completes. How can I show the log messages while the main stored procedure is running?

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        string connString = @"Data Source=MyServer;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=True; Asynchronous Processing=True";

        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
            {
                conn.Open();

                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.RunLongProcess", conn))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;

                    IAsyncResult result = cmd.BeginExecuteNonQuery();

                    while (!result.IsCompleted)
                    {
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);

                        using (SqlConnection connSteps = new SqlConnection(connString))
                        {
                            connSteps.Open();

                            using (SqlCommand cmdSteps = new SqlCommand("EXEC dbo.ReturnProcessSteps", connSteps))
                            {
                                using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdSteps))
                                {
                                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                                    da.Fill(dt);
                                    grdStepsTaken.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
                                }
                            }

                            connSteps.Close();
                        }
                    }

                    cmd.EndExecuteNonQuery(result);
                }

                conn.Close();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
}
```

Comment: The clean way: [`Progress<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.progress-1). The dirty way: [`Application.DoEvents`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.doevents). Does any of these help?

Comment: @RobJ, you need to run ReturnProcessSteps in another thread and update UI as needed. Avoid Application.DoEvents as much as possible.

Comment: As the code will never win a beauty prize: Take the dirty way. Looks like all the logic is put into click events and database, UI access, calculations and logic are all mixed together.

Comment: Thanks, it is working now.  Application.DoEvents did the trick.

Comment: @Delphi.Boy *in another thread and update UI* - that'll only cause more issues

Comment: Consider preventing the button being clicked while the operation is in progress

Comment: @CaiusJard, not if implemented correctly.

Comment: @Delphi.Boy sure, but that's like everything else.. There are many pitfalls waiting for newbies when they "make something multithreaded" so telling them to go that way if they're ill prepared is a recipe for causing more issues. I'd have had zero problem with your comment if it was an answer, that showed/involved and fully explained why it was calling InvokeRequired etc.. But just as a comment that could have been taken as instruction, I feel it's a problem

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - Never ever call `Application.DoEvents()`. It is evil incarnate.

Comment: @Enigmativity could you share horror stories of your programming career where you used `Application.DoEvents` and all hell broke loose?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - Many moons ago I was was working on a Windows Forms App that ended up with intermittent re-entrancy issues. It was a mess trying to work out the cause and it ended up that `Application.DoEvents()` was the culprit - it's not in the stack trace. It's so hard to find.

Answer (score 0):

You've said in the comments that you just rammed an `Application.DoEvents` in there, but it's still an awful approach to the problem because there seemingly isn't anything stopping the user from clicking again, and you jam up the UI thread for 2 seconds at a time with that Sleep

It's not a massive stretch to leverage TAP:

```
    private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string connString = @"Data Source=MyServer;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=True; Asynchronous Processing=True";

        try
        {
            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.RunLongProcess", connString))
            {
                cmd.Connection.Open();
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
                _timer.Start();
                await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
                _timer.Stop();
            } 
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

And then have a DispatcherTimer Tick event do the refreshing the data:

```
    try{
      _timer.Stop();
      using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter("EXEC dbo.ReturnProcessSteps", connString))
      {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        await Task.Run(() => da.Fill(dt));
        grdStepsTaken.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
      }
    } finally{
      _timer.Start();
    }
```

DispatcherTimer will make sure the event is executed using the UI thread. If you're prepared to do this marshalling yourself you could dispense with it, use a normal Timers.Timer and it would't need async on the fill, because you'd be making sure you set the ItemsSource using the UI thread. If you don't understand the significance of that sentence, just use a DispatcherTimer and await ..